# How do i select a data column from a DDDW dynamically in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, datacolumn, datawindow

I'm using PowerBuilder 11.5 and still relatively new to PowerBuilder. I need to get the datacolumn value of the selected item of a DDDW from a popoup window? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By "from a popup window", do you mean from the drop down that appears when the user clicks the arrow (as one example of an event that will create that).

Comment: No I mean actual popup window. On this window is a data window, the data object of that is a data window with 2 dddw on it. The dddw's each have their own data window consisting of a item_code(which is the data column I want) and a item_description( the display column)

Comment: The answer GetItemxxx() still stands, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply I got the datacolumn value by doing a case statement on the dwo.name in the itemchanged event of the datawindow, and storing the data in an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface, the answer is *datawindow*.GetItemxxx () (where xxx is String or Number or ... corresponding to the data type of the column being retrieved).

Good luck,

Terry.